# WPF Minimized and Maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen

I would like to have two startup options in my application, to start it maximized, and to start it minimized. No problem here, but I would also like them to have both checked, and in that case I would like it to start minimized, but if the user clicks the application to show it then it should be maximized (cover the whole screen). I thought that if I first maximized it befor minimizing it should stay that way, but thats not the case, here instead it just get minimized, and then when opened it's in the "normal" state.

```
if (ConfigHandler.Instance.Fullscreen)
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
if (ConfigHandler.Instance.Minimized)
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: Do you set the window to `WindowState.Normal` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's StateChanged event you're looking for.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (ConfigHandler.Instance.Minimized)
            WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
        this.StateChanged += MainWindow_StateChanged;
    }
    void MainWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ConfigHandler.Instance.Fullscreen)
            WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
        this.StateChanged -= MainWindow_StateChanged;//to prevent further effect
    }
```